# Custom Theme Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, customization, color-scheme

I am creating a custom theme at the Moment and am pretty close to the end, but i need to know the name of one specific object, maybe you can help me.

[image]

I need to know, where I can can change that white bar on the left side...
Does anyone know the name to adress it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok Guys,

took me a lot of time but i have it now.
It's simply calles "indicator margin" - yes it is that simple -.-

Thanks anyway